# Can't install VisualSFM macOS High Sierra because it requires cairo-x11 which is no longer supported

Tags: macos, gtk, x11, cairo

I am trying to install VisualSFM on my MacBook Pro mid-2015 running High Sierra for a photogrammetry project I am currently working on with a professor. To do the install  I am using [Dan Monaghan's installer](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer) along with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5XwiOOuJt0) to do the install;however, when I run the installer, I get this error:

```
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/Steven/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gtk+/02.make:
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -                       DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gdk\" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I../.. -I../../gdk -I../../gdk -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DDISABLE_VISIBILITY -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.36.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0_1/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.12/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.4/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.11/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.8.0/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include/cairo -I/opt/X11/include -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -I/opt/X11/include -g -O2 -Wall -c gdkcursor-x11.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gdkcursor-x11.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gdk\" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I../.. -I../../gdk -I../../gdk -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DDISABLE_VISIBILITY -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.36.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0_1/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.12/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.4/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.11/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.8.0/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include/cairo -I/opt/X11/include -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -I/opt/X11/include -g -O2 -Wall -c gdkapplaunchcontext-x11.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gdkapplaunchcontext-x11.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gdk\" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I../.. -I../../gdk -I../../gdk -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DDISABLE_VISIBILITY -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.36.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0_1/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.12/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.4/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.11/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.8.0/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include/cairo -I/opt/X11/include -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -I/opt/X11/include -g -O2 -Wall -c gdkdisplay-x11.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gdkdisplay-x11.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gdk\" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I../.. -I../../gdk -I../../gdk -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DDISABLE_VISIBILITY -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.36.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0_1/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.12/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.4/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.11/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.8.0/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include/cairo -I/opt/X11/include -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -I/opt/X11/include -g -O2 -Wall -c gdkdrawable-x11.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gdkdrawable-x11.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gdk\" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I../.. -I../../gdk -I../../gdk -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DDISABLE_VISIBILITY -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.36.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0_1/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.12/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.4/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.11/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.8.0/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include/cairo -I/opt/X11/include -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -I/opt/X11/include -g -O2 -Wall -c gdkdnd-x11.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gdkdnd-x11.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -DG_LOG_DOMAIN=\"Gdk\" -DGDK_COMPILATION -I../.. -I../../gdk -I../../gdk -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -DDISABLE_VISIBILITY -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.42/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.56.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.36.12/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.34.0_1/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.12/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.4/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.11/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/1.8.0/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.1/include/pango-1.0 -I/opt/X11/include -I/opt/X11/include/cairo -I/opt/X11/include -DG_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DATK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -I/opt/X11/include -g -O2 -Wall -c gdkevents-x11.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gdkevents-x11.o
gdkdrawable-x11.c:32:10: fatal error: 'cairo-xlib.h' file not found
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [gdkdrawable-x11.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
...


cd build; ar -x ../lib/VisualSFM.a; cd ..;
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
g++-4.9 -w -o bin/VisualSFM build/*.* -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -pthread -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -ldl  lib/lapack.a lib/blas.a lib/libf2c.a lib/libjpeg.a 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_cclosure_new", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::GetOpenFilePreview(char const*, char const*, int, int) in RegisterGUI.o
  "_g_free", referenced from:
      RegisterWin::__FileChooserPreview(_GtkFileChooser*, void*)   in RegisterGUI.o
      RegisterWin::__ComboBoxChanged(_GtkComboBox*, void*)   in RegisterGUI.o
...


  "_gtk_window_set_type_hint", referenced from:
      GlobalTasks::InitLogWindow(char const*, int) in GlobalTasks.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [VisualSFM] Error 1
VSFM application failed to build, halting.
```

The problem seems to be do to the fact that it requires cairo with x11;however Apple no longer supports cairo with x11 because of XQuartz. I tried `brew install --with-x11 cairo` but got `Warning: cairo: this formula has no --with-x11 option so it will be ignored!` I am not sure if it would solve my problem with installing VisualSFM, but is there anyway to install an old version of Cairo with X11?